# How to write/override your own assignment function as in `names<-`?

Tags: r, package, variable-assignment, assign

Inspired by the way the `names<-` function works I want to be able to do something similar inside a package.

---

### Reproducible example

Create an empty package and add the following file:

```
## R/internal-state.R
the <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())

#' @export
object <- function(name) the[[name]]

#' @export
set_object <- function(name, value) the[[name]] <- value
```

---

Then on the console:

```
> usethis::use_namespace() ## and choose Yes
> devtools::document()
```

After that, install package with `CTRL+SHIFT+B`

---

Now you can do this:

```
> library(testpackage)
> set_object("foo", 1)
> object("foo")
[1] 1
```

---

### Question

How to modify this example to be able to do that?

```
> library(testpackage)
> object("foo") <- 1
> object("foo")
[1] 1
```

Comment: I would have imagined that your `names<-` equivalent would have attempted to alter an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a function like this if the first value is not "assignable". Here you have the literal string value "foo" and you cannot assign a value to that literal value so the fancy `function<-` syntactic sugar will not work. When you use `names(x) <- "a"` the `x` value is a variable that can be updated. The call is translated to something like

```
x <- `names<-`(x, "a")
```

This means `object("foo") <- 1` would become

```
"foo" <- `object<-`("foo", 1)
```

which doesn't make sense